# How to get message to my gmail if Python script raise exception

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have tried with logging.handlers ,but failed
I took code from the web and i have tried it .

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

smtp_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("smtp.gmail.com", 587),
                                            fromaddr="name@gmail.com", 
                                            toaddrs="name@gmail.com",
                                            subject=u"AppName error!")


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(smtp_handler)

try:
    data= Data
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception('Unhandled Exception')
```

In my code i have used variable data and assigned it with Data which is not even defined hence it throws Exception. I want to get the Exception error to my gmail. How can i achieve it. If any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of figuring out how `smtplib` works, my approach was to install a mailserver on the machine and call that using `os.popen`:

```
def sendmail_email(msg):
    sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
    sendmail = os.popen("{} -t".format(sendmail_location), 'w')
    sendmail.write(msg)
    status = sendmail.close()
    print("Sent the following email with sendmail, status {}:".format(status))
    print(msg)

...
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    message = """To:your_address@domain.com
From:your_program@domain.com
Subject:An exception has occurred.

Hello Father,

An exception has occurred:

{}

Here is the stack trace for the exception:

{}

Thank you,
-The Machine""".format(e.message, traceback.format_exc())
    sendmail_email(message)
```

I got that solution from [this website](http://www.yak.net/fqa/84.html), which I found to be very helpful, though at this point it's somewhat out of date.